# is there a difference between using <Container> and <View> in NativeBase ui library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

[NativeBase](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#anatomy-headref) says to wrap all components inside `<Container></Container>` tag.

1. Does it mean to replace all `<View></View>` tags?
2. Are there any differences in functionality or layout when using all
   `<Container>` tags to replace all `<View>` tags and vice versa?
3. Should I just use one `<Container>` per screen and use `<View>`
   for the rest of the containers inside that screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd point in your question is the correct one. `Container` component should be used only one time per screen to wrap all your children components, it's a bit like `React.Fragment`.

`Container` takes generally three children components

```
<Container>
   <Header> //<-always on top
      ...
   </Header>
   <Content> //<-supports scrolling
      ...
   </Content>
   <Footer> //<-always in the bottom
      ...
   </Footer>
</Container>
```

> Are there any differences in functionality or layout when using all
>    tags to replace all  tags and vice versa?

It's not recommended to replace all `View` with `Container` because `Container` has its default styles and it will not behave the same as if you use `View` component to wrap components.

Comment: Hi, what if I don't use <Container> at all and just use <View> only. What will be the result?

Comment: If you want to use `Header`, `Content` and `Footer` you should wrap them with `Container` component. If you don't use those components you can just wrap your screen with a View. imo if you use native-base library I recommend to follow components anatomy from the docs to avoid components misfunction

Comment: I see, so I have to wrap with <Container> from 'native-base' if the screen contains components from native base.